# Opening a django file to process in python 3.6 is running into typeerror

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

This is what my code looked like in 2.7

```
report = FileContainerModel.objects.get()
lines = report.document.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    dostuff(line.split('\t'))
```

And now with the same code I'm running into this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How should I be approaching this?

Comment: Seems like `line` is a `byte` so `dostuff(line.split(b'\t'))` may be the replacement or just `dostuff(line.decode('utf8').split('\t'))`.

Comment: Ah, that seemed to have fixed the issue. Thanks! @abdou

Comment: So @Abdou should get all the credit for this. But to add a little color, this is an example of a Python 2 to 3 string issue: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data

Comment: @raiderrobert quick question, is it possible to read the file as string instead of binary then?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat, yep, that second recommendation `line.decode('utf8').split('\t')` does exactly that.

Comment: @raiderrobert yeah that's what I've been doing now, but I imagine that there should be a mode to open the file as read string mode instead of read binary mode. No? I've tried open(mode='r') but it's still defaulting to binary unfortunately.

Comment: So the `r` mode for the `open()` function, just designates to be read only: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Oh it behaves differently from the typical open in python? @raiderrobert I believe 'r' was read string, whereas 'rb' was read bytes right? I suppose decoding is the only alternative?

Comment: Yep, here's a better read on what all is going on: http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html